# Convert .txt to .xml

Tags: c#, xml, text

I am looking for a way in C# to input a text file and output an xml. After some searching, I have found ways to input strings and output as xml, and by hand input some text into a C# source code, and output as xml, but not to import a text file and output. I need this as I have an application that saves some computer-specific info to a txt file. I would like to make a C# program that takes this .txt and outputs it as .xml . All .txt files will have the same format. If possible I would like it to output to something like:

```
<Data>
    <Info>#</Info>
```

All the contents of the text file would output into the # area. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? You'll need to read in a txt file with a file stream and then create the XML document yourself in code. There are plenty of samples out there for both, even on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you need to add xml element for every line in txt, you can write similar to following (XLINQ).

```
String[] data = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile.txt");
XElement root = new XElement("root",
                            from item in data
                            select new XElement("Line",item));
root.Save("XmlFile.Xml");
```

Output

```
    <root>
    <Line>Hello</Line>
    <Line>World</Line>
    </root>
```

Comment: Thank you, simple script, easy to understand. Sorry that the question was basic, I am new to C#

Comment: sir is there a way of doing this. please reply sir     <root>
    <Line1>Hello</Line1>
    <Line2>World</Line2>
    </root> Instead of Line can it change to line1,line2 etc.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The following will open a file, read the contents, create a new XML document, and then save the results to the same path as the original, only with an XML extension.

```
var txt = string.Empty;

using (var stream = File.OpenText(pathToFile))
{
    txt = stream.ReadToEnd();
}
var xml = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Data",
        new XElement("Info", txt)));

xml.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(pathToFile, ".xml"));
```

Comment: +1 to HackedByChinese and Tilak samples. Combinig to can even produce single statement converter (new XDocument + ReadAllLines + .Save) :).